# How to split by carriage return (vbCr) and it still keep it in the final string array?

Tags: .net, regex, string, vb.net, split

I have a `testString` in my code that outputs to the following:

- vbLf & "TEST1" & vbCrLf & "TEST2" & vbCrLf & "TEST3" & vbCr

When I do `Dim finalArray = testString.Split(vbCr)`, my `finalString` will be an array with the following contents:

- vbLf & "TEST1"
- vbLf & "TEST2"
- vbLf & "TEST3"

Basically, the split is 'eating' my carriage return.

Is there an efficient way to split by carriage return and still keep `vbCr`? (To avoid placing it one by one again)

Thank you in advance to everyone.

Comment: `string.Split` does not includes the separator into its results.

Comment: @Alejandro Indeed, I'm trying to solve my issue by using ``RegularExpressions.Regex.Split``, but with no sucess up until now.

Comment: `dim finalArray = testString.Split({vbCr}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(Function(s) s & vbCr).ToArray()`

Comment: Thank you very much @Jimi! It's working as you mentioned, will try to understand the code you placed. Regards

Comment: @Jimi's solution will give you the desired result but you should note that it is simply a succinct way of doing the split first and then adding a carriage return to each part afterwards. One potential issue is that it will add a carriage return to the last substring that may not have been there in the first place. The only way to do what you actually asked for, i.e. split up the `String` without removing carriage returns in the first place, would be to use a loop, `IndexOf` and `Substring`.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you know that every entry came from there being a vbCr at the end of it so you can just put them back in whenever you need, for example:

```
File.WriteAllText(path, string.Join(vbCr, finalArray));
```

But then you might find that there is some way of using your array anyway:

```
MyTextBox.Lines = finalArray

File.WriteAllLines(path, finalArray)
```